# Using itertools.groupby Without Changing the Type of the Key?

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I am attempting to organize a large numpy `ndarray` (sets of ~1mil entries of at most 16 dimensions) into two subgroups by two of the dimensions of the array.

Currently, I'm using itertool's `groupby` function, but the values that it creates in my dictionary are `itertools._grouper` objects, where my `ndarray` seems to be converted to a `grouper` object no matter what I do.

While I could make a custom `groupby` function to solve this problem, it seems a fundamental problem in my coding ability in Python, a language to which I'm very new, to be unsure how to either prevent this or convert the `grouper` object back into an `ndarray` with the correct fields.  I need the `ndarray` because its fields need to be maintained for later manipulation.

How would I fix the following code to either convert the returned `groupby` result fully back into an `ndarray` or prevent the conversion?

```
array = np.sort(array, order=['Front','Back','SecStruc'])
front_dict = dict((k,v) for k,v in groupby(array, lambda array : array['Front']))
for key in front_dict:
    front_dict[key] = dict((k,list(v)) for k,v in groupby(front_dict[key], 
    lambda array : front_dict[key]['Back']))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your indentation seems kind of dubious...care to fix that?

Comment: What's the best way to do it?  I'm trying to enforce the 79 char per line limit, but it isn't working particularly well.

Comment: Modified my source accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be able to use `numpy.split` for this. You can split an array into sub-arrays by doing something like:

```
import numpy as np

def findsplit(a):
    diff = a[1:] != a[:-1]
    edges = np.where(diff)[0]
    return edges + 1

array = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4])
s = np.split(array, findsplit(array))
for a in s:
    print a
# [0 0 0]
# [1 1 1 1]
# [2 2]
# [3]
# [4 4 4]
```

To get the nested dictionaries you discribe in your question you could do something like:

```
byFront = np.split(array, findsplit(array['Front']))
front_dict = {}
for sameFront in byFront:
    back_dict = {}
    byBack = np.split(sameFront, findsplit(sameFront['Back']))
    for sameBack in byBack:
        back_dict[sameBack['Back'][0]] = sameBack
    front_dict[sameFront['Front'][0]] = back_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are almost there.  `list(v)` is a list than can easily be converted to an array.

```
x=np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4])
{k:np.array(list(v)) for k,v in groupby(x)}

{0: array([0, 0, 0]),
 1: array([1, 1, 1, 1]),
 2: array([2, 2]),
 3: array([3]),
 4: array([4, 4, 4])}
```

Or with a 2d array (grouping on the 1st column, and then on the last column).

```
x=np.array([[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,0,4],[2,3,1]])
d={k:list(v) for k,v in groupby(x,lambda s:s[0])}
print d
# {0: [array([0, 1, 2])],
#  1: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 4]), array([1, 0, 4])],
#  2: [array([2, 3, 1])]}
for i in d.keys():
    d[i]={k:np.array(list(v)) for k,v in groupby(list(d[i]),lambda s:s[2])}
print d
# {0: {2: array([[0, 1, 2]])},
#  1: {3: array([[1, 2, 3]]), 4: array([[1, 2, 4], [1, 0, 4])},
#  2: {1: array([[2, 3, 1]])}}
print d[1][4]
#  [[1 2 4]
#   [1 0 4]]
```

It doesn't matter much whether I use `list(v)` or `np.array(list(v))` - at either stage (provided you are interested in iterating on the 1st dimension).

---

using a structured array adapted from the numpy documentation

```
x = np.array([(1.5,2.5,(1.0,2.0)),(1.5,2.5,(2.0,4.0)),(3.,4.,(4.,5.)),(1.,3.,(2.,6.))],
        dtype=[('x','f4'),('y',np.float32),('value','f4',(2,2))])
d={k:list(v) for k,v in groupby(x,lambda s:s['x'])}
for i in d.keys():
    d[i]={k:list(v) for k,v in groupby(list(d[i]),lambda s:s['y'])}
pprint(d)
for dd in d[1.5][2.5]:
    print dd
print d[1.5][2.5][0].dtype
# [('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('value', '<f4', (2, 2))]
dd = np.array(d[1.5][2.5],dtype=x.dtype)
print dd
print dd.dtype
print dd[0]
# (1.5, 2.5, [[1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0]])
print dd['value']
# [[[ 1.  2.] [ 1.  2.]]
#  [[ 2.  4.] [ 2.  4.]]]
```

The structured array character of the 'innermost' elements is preserved.  I only need to use `np.array(...,dtype=x.dtype)` if I want to turn a list of these arrays into one array (e.g. `dd`).

In `d[1.5][2.5][0]['value']`, `1.5` and `2.5` are dictionary keys, `0` is a list index, and `value` is a structure array field name.

---

But is this use of `groupby` really needed?  I can get that last 'value' with normal numpy indexing.  And the 'rows' of `x` don't have to be sorted.  With a very large array, speed and memory use could be important considerations.

```
I=(x['x']==1.5)&(x['y']==2.5)
print x[I]['value']
```

Comment: When converting directly to Numpy array, I get a void array with object members using buffer.  I'm not sure what that is.

When converting to Numpy array after, the Numpy array doesn't maintain the field labels.

Comment: My test case used a purely numeric array. It is easy to convert that to and from lists. `groupby` is a Python function that works with lists and generators. You are using structured arrays. Look at what `array.tolist()` produces.  This is what `groupby` is going to work with.  When you convert a list produced by `groupby` back to an array, you will need to specify the `dtype`, e.g. `np.array(list(v),dtype=array.dtype)`.

Comment: Tried that already.  It gives a void type error.  Unless there's a very well defined dataset, creating np arrays is prone to void type error.  
Otherwise, your solution is far more elegant.

Comment: Can you give us a simple example of your array? It's not obvious what you mean by well defined dataset, or conversely, one that isn't well defined.  How does it differ from the simple structured array example that I just added?

Comment: The difference is in the dtypes.  I've looked into it a little more and the problem is the way that Numpy handles lists, where it attempts to handle them is as native a form as possible.  Really, it's rather beautiful.
Looking at the dtypes, Front has type '0' and back has type '0' as well because, I suppose, they contain various types of data according to the method I use to construct the array.
When trying to create the new array, it cannot create the structured ndarray because of these unpredictable types.

The problem is my nasty data.  A column of mixed types occurs rarely.

Comment: I'm unsure what level of detail is appropriate (still figuring out StackOverflow and its standards on posts), but the code snippet is part of some computational biology code for doing multidimensional kernel density estimations in various groups.  The dataset I'm working with comes from another source, and I didn't realise that it had some very odd values for some of the front and back samples, each of which *should* be a 3 letter amino acid code.  So next up are methods to filter the data and then the application of your solution.

Comment: So it sounds as though you can manipulate `array`, removing lines, or splitting it.  But you can't recreate a similar array from the lists that `groupby` generates.